# Единый шрифт в Google Spreadsheets

Tags: шрифты, google-spreadsheet

Вставляем в таблицу копипастом с разных мест, при этом начинается полный хаос - разный текст, размер и цвета.

Если с цветом проблему можно решить условным форматированием, то как быть с размером и шрифтом?

Есть ли способ для автоматической конвертации в дефолтный (или заданный) шрифт и размер при вставке текста?

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + V?

Answer (score 0):

1) Правой кнопкой мыши по ячейке
2) Специальная вставка
3) Выберите способ вставки из списка (в вашем случае "Вставить только значение (V)")
 
**(Пример на изображении)**

[image: Специальная вставка]